# Deriving reward functions in Sutton & Barto

Tags: probability, reinforcement-learning, conditional-expectation

[image]

Does anyone know how the equations have been derived, I'm still learning probablity theory and expectations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of the expectation you have:
$$ \mathbb{E}[R_t|S_{t-1}=s,A_{t-1}=a]=\sum_{r\in\mathcal{R}}r p(r|s,a), $$
where $r$ are the (discrete) values taken by the random variable $R_t$. Then using probability marginalization: $p(r|s,a)=\sum_{s'\in\mathcal{S}}p(r,s'|s,a)$ you get the result.

For the second equation, you apply the same definion:
$$ \mathbb{E}[R_t|S_{t-1}=s,A_{t-1}=a,S_t=s']=\sum_{r\in\mathcal{R}}r p(r|s,a,s'), $$
and you get the result  using the definition of conditional probability: $p(r|s,a,s')=\frac{p(r,s'|s,a)}{p(s'|s,a)}$.